# Open my app from a FB app status (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink, status

I am trying to open my app via the Facebook app's status but my link shows up as text instead of a link. It does works with both SMS and Email but does not FB or Twitter status'.

I have a URL Scheme set up in my Info.plist.
My link is  (appName is my URL Scheme name given)

Also I am calling FB, Twitter, & everything else with

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
{
    bubbleTable.typingBubble = NSBubbleTypingTypeNobody;

    NSBubbleData *sayBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:textField.text date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeMine];
    [bubbleData addObject:sayBubble];
    [bubbleTable reloadData];

    textField.text = @"";

    NSLog(@"%@, %d", activityType, completed);
}];


[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Trying to keep everything native to iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks for your Use Case.

Comment: I've looked into this and we are trying to avoid the FB SDK. We are currently calling Facebook with the 
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

Comment: I am marking this as the answer cause it appears this is the only way to open an app with a link in a FB Status. Thank you for your time Tobi.